# Unusual Markov inequality for normal distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, probability-inequalities, inequality

I'm trying to answer the following question from Larry Wassermans book on statistical inference.

[image]

My question is how did they arrive at the Markov bound, it does not seem like the normal form of the Markov inequality i.e. $P(Z > t) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(Z)}{t}$. Also how could we analytically calculate $\mathbb{E}(|Z|^k)$.

Comment: Apply the "normal form" of the equality to the random variable $|Z|^k.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that the [Markov inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) applies to *non-negative* random variables; you can't apply it directly to $Z$.

Let $Y=|Z|^k$ for $k>0$, which is non-negative. Now apply the Markov inequality to $Y$, then relate that back to a probability statement about $|Z|$. (Edit: as whuber already noted in comments; not sure how I missed that)

As for evaluating $E(|Z|^k)$, there's several ways to approach it. Let's take a fairly straightforward one -- just write the integral, use the symmetry of $|Z|$ to write it in terms of an integral on the positive half line, and then make an obvious substitution to get a [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).